# How to create project notification scheme with JIRA Soap

Tags: soap, jira

i want to create a RemoteScheme , with set new mail notifications , then update jira project with new mail notifications i created use jira soap api.

can any one give some ideas?

thinks!

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest way is to create a new JIRA plugin that provides a new SOAP endpoint. Usually less than a day's work but since it involves notification schemes it's probably a couple of days to get right. This all assumes you're comfortable writing JIRA plugins and writing Java.